# Type mismatch error in initialization of Scala map (string to object)

Tags: scala, types, dictionary

I need to setup a Scala Map that maps from String to an object (string, integer, floating point number)

I tried this code:

```
val m = Map[String, Object]("A"->10, "B"->20.5)
```

to get type mismatch error.

[image]

What could be the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strictly speaking Scala `Int` is not a subtype of `Object`, but it is a subtype of `AnyVal`:

```
val m = Map[String, AnyVal]("A"->10, "B"->20.5)
```

Where `AnyVal` is a common super type of all Scala primitives, I always refer to this image which illustrates the type hierarchy:

[image]
<sub>(source: [verrech.net](http://lmazy.verrech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/scala_type_hierarchy.png))</sub>

If you want a common supertype with `scala.Scala.Object` or of `java.lang.Object` use `Any`.

[Here](http://lmazy.verrech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/scala_type_hierarchy.png) is the link to the image.